# What is the purpose of MVC passing the current "controller" and "action" as parameter values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I had to pass an extra parameter with my action links to indicate where they came from (as I needed to change a back link in the pages accordingly).

As it was a controller name, I decided to name it `controller`.

e.g. a sample link might be:

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Options", "Questionnaire", new { 
     id = item.QuestionnaireId, 
     controller = "templates" }, null)
```

The receiving action in `QuestionnaireController` looked like:

```
public ActionResult Options(int id, string controller)
```

When the action was hit I noticed the controller value was not `template`, but instead was the name of the *current controller* (i.e. `QuestionnaireController`).

As an experiment I added an `action` parameter e.g.:

```
public ActionResult Options(int id, string controller, string action)
```

the action value was the *current action* too (i.e. `Options`).

My work-around for this was simply to rename my parameter to `source`, but **why does MVC bother to map the names `controller` and `action` to action parameters?** I assume that would apply to any/all Route Mapping values, but what is the purpose of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does MVC bother to map the names controller and action to action parameters?

I believe it's done as part of the [QueryStringValueProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.querystringvalueprovider(v=vs.118).aspx) or one of the other ValueProviders (maybe the [RouteDataValueProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.routedatavalueprovider%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)).  ASP.Net MVC uses [Convention over Configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration), so the framework uses the values provided to populate method parameters.  The Controller name, Action name and even the Area name are all values provided in the Url.

> I assume that would apply to any/all Route Mapping values, but what is the purpose of this?

The ValueProvider is used for Routing data to determine the matching route to use, it also happens to be the same object that provides the data to populate method parameters.  The side affect you are experiencing is most likely not a *feature* they were trying to implement.

The [DefaultModelBinder.GetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultmodelbinder.getpropertyvalue(v=vs.118).aspx) uses the ValueProviders to locate a value and bind it to the model (or method paramater).